# Title not visible in Custom Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I'm trying to implement a Custom Toolbar, but i cant manage to get the title in it.
I've tried many posts on StackOverflow but without succes.

**Activity_Main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.diong.amyappname">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.diong.amyApp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

I really tried a lot.

- Trying to set the title using getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
- I tried other pc's with new projects.
- I tried to user other methods

If someone could help me out that would be awesome!

***UPDATE***

I've found "a" fix,
In the toolbar.xml add:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:title="@string/app_name"
```

Now it works but..
I see that the code was suggested in the MainActivity.java is doing nothing

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

toolbar.setTitle("Your title here");

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Can someone help me out?

***UPDATE 2.0***

I found a error and i found out that the title is working fine on the virtual device or my phone, just not in the preview design

[IDE Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBrV9.png)

[IDE Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN6Mw.png)

[IDE Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A094j.png)

[IDE Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f90UQ.png)

[IDE Error Screenshot 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHduA.png)

[IDE Error Screenshot 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRAVD.png)

Comment: Without adding `app:title`, what are you seeing when you run the app? Just a solid color toolbar with no text? When I copy your code into my own project, I see the app name in the toolbar.

Comment: Yes i just see a solid color toolbar with no text...

Comment: Is there any chance that the text color of your toolbar is the same as its background color?

Comment: @BenP. Hello! This is not the case, altought i updated my post with some more info and full screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your id `toolbar` is the id of your `include` tag, but not of the `Toolbar`.
So try to delete the `include` tag and replace it with your `Toolbar`.
Dont forget to add the id to your `Toolbar`.
Then it should work.

**Activity_Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar          
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
     android:elevation="4dp"
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      >

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

> To change the title add `getSupportActionBar.setTitle("Your title");` to your MainActivity.

Comment: Hello! I've used your code as well and adapted everything without any succes. Still no title

Answer (score 0):

Take the id set inside `include` tag and put it inside `Toolbar` tag. Here the include places the `Toolbar.xml` inside the `Activity_Main.xml` but does not affect the `id` to `Toolbar`. So your XMLs should be like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this for the toolbar:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And remember to set your title, if you want it dynamically can proceed this way:

```java
package com.example.diong.amyApp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

         toolbar.setTitle("Your title here");

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't shoot. We can see the answer with the lower case too. :)

Comment: :-D hahaha my keyboard switched into caps mode itself and I didn't realize. Thank you. Do I need to edit ?

Comment: That would be great. However, never used `setTitle` alone. Wouldn't it be better to use : `toolbar.setTitle(String..)`

Comment: Hello! I've used your code and adapted everything without any succes. Still no title

Comment: Was there any special message inside the log? Or what was the result? Did the toolbar appear in the activity design before run?

Comment: Nothing changed.

But i found "a" fixed, ill put it in the post

Comment: Even when following this tutorial no succes https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-app-toolbar

Comment: I created a simple project to test and I can see that it works. I will go on searching. But if you find something working for you please share.

Comment: @gratienasimbahwe Hello! I've updated the post with even more info (title is showing on phone) and screenshots of the IDE and a error

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the real "live" title to appear in the IDE preview.

The preview doesn't know about the code executed in your activity's `onCreate()` method (even if you specify `tools:context` on your root view). That means that the preview doesn't know that this `Toolbar` is your activity's *action bar*, and so it doesn't know that it should display the title. Additionally, it won't know about any `setTitle()` calls made in your activity.

However, you could add `tools:title` to the toolbar itself, so that you see *some* text there. That will show you how the title would appear, so you can see text color/size/etc in the preview.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you need to make changes in your code like:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml(
            "<font color='#673AB7'><b>Your Title</b></font>")
```